# Has anyone successfully used Braze/Appboy with Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, appboy, braze

[Braze/Appboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appboy-web-sdk) can be used with `Vue` but there's no `Nuxt` version and "braze nuxt" or "appboy nuxt" yields zero result on Google.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54729726/871404) proposes a way to install a regular `npm` package on `Nuxt`, however would that solution also work for `Braze`?

I cannot check for myself because I don't have a Braze account at the moment (there's no free version or anything like that) hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His solution is indeed working, you only need to use `mode` rather than `ssr` as I've commented. For more information, you can follow this documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/

But yeah, Nuxt can basically use any package that is working with VueJS !